# Associate newly created record with case that gets created for it

Tags: process-builder

I have a process builder that creates a case when a certain object record is created. I have a field on the case that I want to use to reference this newly created object record. How can I update this field so it references the record that the case was just created for using process builder?

Thanks

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: please see [ask] for getting the most from the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are sveral ways to do this. When your org uses the Lightning interface, an Action in combination with Process Builder is probably the easiest way:

1. create an Action on the 'certain object' to create a new record on Case. Go to the Object Menu in setup > Buttons, Links and Action > Click New Action.
2. In the Next Step, delete all fields from the page layout and ignore the warning message
3. In the 'predefined fields' section, use the formula editor to point your reference field to the Case ID

Next, you use Process Builder to call this Action when a new record in your 'certain object' is created